# reorder LineString coordinates GeoJson

Tags: javascript, maps, geojson, turfjs

I have a large set of GeoJson data made up of many LineStrings. I need to reorder the coordinates of all the LineStrings so that there's as little zig-zag as possible. so for example i have this set of coordinates:

```
[
      [
        -149.858345,
        61.217461,
        0
      ],
      [
        -151.544282,
        59.646368,
        0
      ],
      [
        -124.099861,
        43.982118,
        0
      ],
      [
        -151.291694,
        60.689824,
        0
      ]
]
```

which results in this line

[image]

where instead it should be reordered like this

```
[
     [
        -149.858345,
        61.217461,
        0
      ],
      [
        -151.291694,
        60.689824,
        0
      ],
      [
        -151.544282,
        59.646368,
        0
      ],
      [
        -124.099861,
        43.982118,
        0
      ]
]
```

which renders this

[image]

which is a much more sensible line.

I realize "sensible" is subjective here, another way to look at it, is how do I reorder the coordinates so I get the straightest line?

Is this something I might use turf.js for? i looked through the documentation but couldn't find an appropriate function ( or maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way )

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in with Turf for this, and this tends to be one of those problems that has common-sense solutions if you're a person but is hard to define to a computer. That said, how I'd solve this is:

- Take each coordinate in the line
- Find the optimal tour - https://github.com/perrygeo/optimal_tour or https://github.com/yanatan16/d3-tsp-demo will do the trick with modifications

Another way to do it would be:

- Use turf-concave or concaveman to generate a [concave hull](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/what-are-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions-for-concave-hull) around the points
- Iterate through the segments of the hull, identify the longest one, and remove it, to make the polygon into a LineString.

Comment: thanks @tmcw, i actually already tried the concave hull approach ( with some degree of success... but ultimately not perfect ), i think ultimately your right though... common-sense solutions that are hard to define in algorithmic terms... though at this point these are the only reasonable approaches i think ( outside of approaching my problem entirely differently )